# How can I get my window with tableview to show immediately?

Tags: cocoa, loading, nstableview

How can I get my window with tableview to show immediately rather than having user wait?

The tableview is dependent data that takes awhile to compute so I would prefer to have window with a progress indicator appear immediately. I have selected "Visible at launch" within the Attributes inspector, yet the window doesn't load until the computed data is finished--about 20 seconds.

Comment: is your window in a separate XIB file from the one that contains your main menu?  how do you load that XIB and/or window controller?  Can you show a bit of your code?

Comment: The window is indeed in a separate XIB file. Unfortunately this arrangement makes my code complex and probably not too helpful to show. In any case I initiate this other XIB file from the application's delegate and this should allow me to immediately show the window--but it doesn't. I should add that my tableview in the window is bound to an array controller that gets populated as its data gets computed. This is probably the why I can't load the window straight away. If so, the question is: how does one load such at window before its array controller is flushed with data?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t load the tableView immediately on launch—just have the window show with the tableView empty.

Later, in your application delegate’s:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

method (or in a document didLoad method) fire off the loading of your data.

Comment: I initiate this other XIB file from the application's delegate and this should allow me to immediately show the window--but it doesn't. I should add that my tableview in the window is bound to an array controller that gets populated as its data gets computed. This is probably the why I can't load the window straight away. If so, the question is: how does one load such at window before its array controller is flushed with data?

Answer (score 0):

A solution was to run my slow computation method on a separate thread by using this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(analysizeAndSetDataForErrorWordList:) withObject:completeErrorWordList];
```

Within this method, however, I needed to call methods back on the main thread. I was able to do this with this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addToErrorFoundArrayController:) withObject:thisData waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Now the window bearing the array controller-bound tableView no longer blocks but displays while it's being loaded with the processing data. Now my user is dazzled rather than confused.